# Encoding cyrilllic letters?

Tags: python, encoding

I need to change cyrillic letters to latin letters in string(let's consider only two letters for short):

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 import re 
 vac = {'а': 'a', 'б': 'b'}
 s = 'абба'
 re.sub('а', vac['а'], s)
 re.sub('б', vac['б'], s)
 print s # works fine, prints "abba" 
 s = 'абба'
 # doesn't work in loop
 for ch in vac:
     s = re.sub(unicode(ch, 'utf-8'), vac[unicode(ch, 'utf-8')], s)
 print s
```

UPD: Thank you, guys. Based on your answers, I coded the working function:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 def translit(s):
     symbols = (u"абвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфхъыьэюАБВГДЕЁЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЪЫЬЭЬЬЮ",
     u"abvgdeezijklmnoprstufh'y'euABVGDEEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFH'Y'EU")
     tr = {ord(a):ord(b) for a, b in zip(*symbols)}
     vac = {u'я': 'ya', u'ж': 'zh', u'ц': 'ts', u'ч': 'ch', u'ш': 'sh', u'щ': 'sch', u'Я': 'Ya', u'Ч': 'Ch', u'Ш': 'Sh', u'Щ': 'Sch', u'Ж': 'Zh', u'Ц': 'Ts'}

     s = s.translate(tr)
     s = ''.join([vac.get(c, c) for c in s])
     return s

 s = u"Лорем ипсум, напиши translit'ом"
 a = translit(s)
 print a
```

Comment: There's no way your first code can work, you're not storing the output of `re.sub` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the dictionary keys and the string to a unicode string, do that by prefixing a `u`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
vac = {'а': 'a', u'б': 'b'}
s = u'абба'
print ''.join([vac.get(c, c) for c in s])
```

Output:

```
аbbа
```

Answer (score 0):

`Regex` is not the right tool for your Job. Unfortunately, `unicode.encode` cannot convert to `latin` in a uniform way, so your best bet is to use `unicode.translate`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
symbols = (u"абвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфхъыьэАБВГДЕЁЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЪЫЬЭ",
           u"abvgdeezijklmnoprstufh'y'eABVGDEEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFH'Y'E")
tr = {ord(a):ord(b) for a, b in zip(*symbols)}
s = u'абба'
print s.translate(tr)
```

The benefit is, you don;t need to run this in loop

You may also wan;t to try the python package [transliterate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate)